# How to remove vertical spacing of first row of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I've a ViewController and TableView in it.

When I'm trying to configure my cell I'm getting this space between top and prototype start (from the very top to words "prototype cell")

[image]

In running mode it seems very bad

[image]

It appears when I'm selecting PrototypeCellsCount to 1 any way I tried. Please help me to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking "Adjust Scroll View Insets" in the builder. This is what usually fixes spacing issues like this.

Answer (score 2):

It's like a kind of bug, sometimes happens, sometimes not, try to adjust the `contentInset` in your `viewDidLoad()` like in the following way:

```
// The value depends of some factors, you need to play around it
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-65, 0, 0, 0)
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thx, it resolved my problem for a half because vertical scroller height is not normal http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/Snimokekrana2015-10-15v22.1444937277.png

Comment: If it solve your question, please accept it to can help someone else.

Comment: "for a half". As problems with vertical scroller appeared, it's not the optimal solving